# Prevent Default Enter on Form

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms, submit, enter

My form contain about 10 input text boxes ,The problem is when I press the enter key from a input text box it's directly going to submit button by skipping the text boxes between them.I added my snippet below.it's working fine when using mouse

```js
function getElement(elm){
    var elem = document.getElementById(elm);
    return elem;
}


function sendData(){
    getElement('submit-button').addEventListener("click",function(){
        getElement("success-txt").removeClass('display-none');
        if(getElement('pbarcode')){
            var pbarcode = $('#pbarcode').val();
            var pname = $('#pname').val();
            var pprice = $('#pprice').val();
            var poprice = $('#poprice').val();
            $.ajax({
                     url:'getdata.php',
                     method:"post",
                     data:{pbarcode:pbarcode,pname:pname,pprice:pprice,poprice:poprice},
                     cache: false,
                     onSuccess: function(response){
                                alert('success');
                     },
                     onFailure: function(response){
                                alert('failure');
                     }
            });
        }
        else{
           alert("error"); 
        }

    });
}


function showWarnMessage(){
    getElement("submit-button").addEventListener("click",function(){
       alert("you enteres submitt button");
       var data1 = $('#pbarcode').val();
       var data2 = $('#pname').val();
       var data3 = $('#pprice').val();
       var l3 = data3.length;
       var l1 = data1.length;
       var l2 = data2.length;
       var flag = 0;
       if(l1 < 1){
     
           flag = 1;
       }
       if(l2 < 1){
           flag = 1;
           
       }
       if(l3 < 1){
           flag = 1;
       }
       alert(flag);
       if (flag == '0'){
           alert(flag + "go");
           sendData();
       }
    });
}

showWarnMessage();
```

```css
ul,li {
list-style : none;
padding :0px;
margin : 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="create-user" method="post">
                            <ul id="create-new-user-page">
                                <li>
                                    <span>Product Barcode</span>
                                    <input type="number" id="pbarcode" name="barcode" class="form-data" required>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <span>Product Name</span>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-data" name="pname" id="pname" required>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <span>Product Price</span>
                                    <input type="number" class="form-data" name="pprice" id="pprice" required>
                                  
                                </li>
                               
                                <li>
                                    <input type="submit" id="submit-button"  Value="Submit" name="submit_data">
                                </li>
                
                            </ul>
                            
                        </form>
```

What I have been tried so far is using

> event.preventDefault();

on 'enter' click on text box ,I added the codes below

```
function preventDefault(elem){
   getElement('elem').addEventListener('keypress',function(){
       if (event.keyCode == 13) {
            event.preventDefault();
            alert('calling ')
       }
   }); 
}
preventDefault('pname');
preventDefault('pprice');
preventDefault('pname');
preventDefault('pbarcode');
```

but which also returns the same result.I would like to have a form which works fine with the enter key.(ie,when I press 'enter' key from one input text box which should move in to the next text box ,instead moving directly in to the form submit button)

Answer (score 0):

you can change the button type submit to **button**.

```html
<input type="button" id="submit-button"  Value="Submit" name="submit_data">
```